# What is the normal temperature for a Retina 15" unibody mid-2015 MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

The CPU and GPU temperatures while browsing the web.

Answer (score 1):

Normal temperatures are around 30-50 C (86-122 F). Mine is around 30.6 C on low load and around 60-65C under very heavy load. It depends where you keep you mac, for example if you put it on bed sheets it can get very hot because the air flow is blocked :)